# Como posso evitar repetir código?

Tags: java, android

Tenho um comando que vai precisar realizar vários executes, mas tenho que colocar 1,2,3... , tem como usar o mesmo nome ?

```
 btnadd1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //new Activity_addinf.onbuttonclickHttpPost().execute();
            HttpConnection postCatLivro = new HttpConnection(Activity_addinf.this,
                    catliv.toString(),
                    "http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=%20tx_cat%3D%22Direito%22",
                    0);

            HttpConnection postCatLivro2 =  new HttpConnection(Activity_addinf.this,
                  catliv.toString(),

            "http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DRomance",
                  2);



            postCatLivro.execute();
            postCatLivro2.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre que verificar que está a repetir código a primeira abordagem é isolá-lo em um método. O método deverá ter parâmetros para receber o que é diferente:

```
private void postCatLivro(String url, int seq){
    HttpConnection postCatLivro = new HttpConnection(Activity_addinf.this, catliv.toString(),
                                                     url, seq);
    postCatLivro.execute();
}
```

Use assim:

```
btnadd1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=%20tx_cat%3D%22Direito%22", 0);
        postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DRomance", 2);
    }
}
```

A diferença pode parecer pouca, mas fica "mais arrumado", mais [DRY](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Se verificar que o que é feito nesse método não deve ser da responsabilidade dessa classe escreva uma nova classe.

Comment: Era isso que eu precisava,só não sabia explicar , obrigada !!